# Center Image in Print Preview C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, printing

I'm using WinForms. In my form I have a picturebox and a print button. Is there a way for the images i load into the picturebox to always be in the center of the print preview window? The image below shows my form and an image in the print preview screen that is not centered.

[image]

[image]

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Nav\Pictures\Test_Image.png");
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image,50,50);
    }

    private void Btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: instead of absolute/fixed coordinates (`50, 50`), calculate the center

Comment: You didn't draw the image at the center of document. You draw it at `(50,50)`

Comment: I see, so i'm guessing there is not like a  e.image.center way to do this.

Comment: If i use `e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, e.MarginBounds);` it kinda gives it a margin but it stretches the image as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't draw the image at the center of document. You draw it at `(50,50)`. Instead you can draw it at center of document using [`DrawImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawImage_System_Drawing_Image_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) this way:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,
                     (e.PageBounds.Width - img.Width) / 2,
                     (e.PageBounds.Height - img.Height) / 2,
                     img.Width,
                     img.Height);
```

Comment: Thanks for another great answer! :)